# DDD, Is domain model a domain or a sub-domain

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

These terms make me confuse, please help me understand it a little bit more. So what exactly is a **Domain** in DDD. So my understanding is, **Domain** is an entity or a class in my code and I start asking myself what is the sub-domain then? I want to give an example of an e-commerce system. Here's how I define each term.

```
// My understanding is, this class is a domain. 
// So domain model is actually a domain living inside of e-commerce bounded context.

package io.joseph.e-commerce.domain;

class ShoppingCart {
  private String shoppingCartId;
}
```

but yeah I think I miss understanding something since I don't know what is the sub-domain here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Every software program relates to some activity or interest of its user.  That subject area to which the user applies the program is the *domain* of the software.   Some domains involve the physical world: The domain of an airline-booking program involves real people getting on real aircraft.  Some domains are intangible: The domain of an accounting program is money and finance.  Software domains usually  have little to do with computers, though there are exceptions: The domain of a source-code control system is software development itself.  -- Eric Evans, Domain Driven Design, 2004

So the domain is the thing that your program is about - the problem that you are trying to solve (ex: Cargo Shipping).

> A domain model is not a particular diagram; it is the idea that the diagram is intended to convey.  It is not just the knowledge in a domain expert's head; *it is a rigorously organized and selective abstraction of that knowledge.*

The code is our attempt to describe to the machine how to manipulate information and messages the same way that our "rigorously organized and selective abstraction" would.

The realization of a domain model in code is a likely to involve a lot of classes (not just one); and there are likely to be a lot of classes that aren't part of the domain at all (ex: I/O; message parsing; logging/monitoring/observability, and so on).